# Error to load packages installed using apm link in Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-7-x64, atom-editor

Today I installed the Atom Editor (manually and using choco) - version: 0.136.0.

After that, I install packages using apm link, because I'm behind a company proxy and this is the best solution for me.

But, when I open Atom, **I get a lot errors:** https://gist.github.com/patrickmaciel/569f7ad38e47f01210fd

For example:

```
Failed to load package named 'atom-color-highlight' Error: Cannot find module 'emissary'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:344:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:373:17)
```

And...

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'season' module.js:346
Error activating package config for “ask-stack” Error {code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", stack: (...), message: "Cannot find module 'request'"} c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Atom.0.136.0\tools\Atom\resources\app\node_modules\settings-view\lib\…:416
Error activating package config for “atom-color-highlight” Error {code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", stack: (...), message: "Cannot find module 'emissary'"} c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Atom.0.136.0\tools\Atom\resources\app\node_modules\settings-view\lib\…:416
Error activating package config for “atom-spotify” Error {code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", stack: (...), message: "Cannot find module 'spotify-node-applescript'"} c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Atom.0.136.0\tools\Atom\resources\app\node_modules\settings-view\lib\…:416
Error activating package config for “autocomplete-plus” Error {code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", stack: (...), message: "Cannot find module 'underscore-plus'"} c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Atom.0.136.0\tools\Atom\resources\app\node_modules\settings-view\lib\…:416
Error activating package config for “autocomplete-snippets” Error {code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", stack: (...), message: "Cannot find module 'underscore-plus'"} c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Atom.0.136.0\tools\Atom\resources\app\node_modules\settings-view\lib\…:416
Error activating package config for “autoprefixer” Error {code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", stack: (...), message: "Cannot find module 'autoprefixer-core'"} c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Atom.0.136.0\tools\Atom\resources\app\node_modules\settings-view\lib\…:416
Error activating package config for “change-case” Error {code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", stack: (...), message: "Cannot find module 'change-case'"} c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Atom.0.136.0\tools\Atom\resources\app\node_modules\settings-view\lib\…:416
Error activating package config for “csscomb” Error {code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", stack: (...), message: "Cannot find module 'csscomb'"} c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Atom.0.136.0\tools\Atom\resources\app\node_modules\settings-view\lib\…:416
Error activating package config for “csslint” Error {code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", stack: (...), message: "Cannot find module 'atom-keymap-plus'"} c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Atom.0.136.0\tools\Atom\resources\app\node_modules\settings-view\lib\…:416
Error activating package config for “emmet” Error {code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", stack: (...), message: "Cannot find module 'emmet'"} c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Atom.0.136.0\tools\Atom\resources\app\node_modules\settings-view\lib\…:416
Error activating package config for “fancy-new-file” Error {code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", stack: (...), message: "Cannot find module 'mkdirp'"} c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Atom.0.136.0\tools\Atom\resources\app\node_modules\settings-view\lib\…:416
Error activating package config for “highlight-line” Error {code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", stack: (...), message: "Cannot find module 'event-kit'"} c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Atom.0.136.0\tools\Atom\resources\app\node_modules\settings-view\lib\…:416
Error activating package config for “jshint” Error {code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", stack: (...), message: "Cannot find module 'emissary'"} c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Atom.0.136.0\tools\Atom\resources\app\node_modules\settings-view\lib\…:416
Error activating package config for “markdown-preview” Error {code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", stack: (...), message: "Cannot find module 'fs-plus'"} c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Atom.0.136.0\tools\Atom\resources\app\node_modules\settings-view\lib\…:416
Error activating package config for “Search” Error {code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", stack: (...), message: "Cannot find module 'open'"} c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Atom.0.136.0\tools\Atom\resources\app\node_modules\settings-view\lib\…:416
Error activating package config for “terminal-status” Error {code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", stack: (...), message: "Cannot find module 'domify'"} c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Atom.0.136.0\tools\Atom\resources\app\node_modules\settings-view\lib\…:416
Error activating package config for “todo-show” Error {code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", stack: (...), message: "Cannot find module 'fs-plus'"} c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Atom.0.136.0\tools\Atom\resources\app\node_modules\settings-view\lib\…:416
Error activating package config for “uglify” Error {code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", stack: (...), message: "Cannot find module 'uglify-js'"} c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Atom.0.136.0\tools\Atom\resources\app\node_modules\settings-view\lib\…:416
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'glob'
```

I don't know how to fix that.

*I'm using Windows 7*.

---

Sorry for my english...

**If you need more information, tell me (before down vote)**

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue at Github related to the apm load - https://github.com/jakemarsh/atom-spotify/issues/10 - hopefully they will fix it sometime.